# NHibernate mapping problem - Could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: nhibernate, proxy, nhibernate-mapping

I have just started to learn NHibernate, and are following tutorials. On my own learning project, I have made up a problem for myself. I have two tables:

```
Team:
TeamId*
Name


Match:
MatchId*
TeamAId
TeamBId
```

The model entities are:

Team

```
public virtual int? TeamId { get; private set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual IList<Match> HomeMatches { get; set; }
public virtual IList<Match> AwayMatches { get; set; }
```

Match

```
public virtual int? MatchId { get; private set; }
public virtual Team TeamA { get; set; }
public virtual Team TeamB { get; set; }
```

And this is my mapping for Team:

```
    <property name="Name" type="string">
        <column name="Name" sql-type="nvarchar" not-null="true"/>
    </property>


    <bag name="HomeMatches" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key column="TeamAId" />
        <one-to-many class="Match"/>
    </bag>

    <bag name="AwayMatches" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key column="TeamBId" />
        <one-to-many class="Match"/>
    </bag>
```

And this is for Match:

```
    <many-to-one name="TeamA" class="Team">
        <column name="TeamAId" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>

    <many-to-one name="TeamB" class="Team">
        <column name="TeamBId" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
```

I guess this isn't the right way to do it, since I get an error message:
NHibernate.LazyInitializationException: Initializing[MyProject.Domain.Entities.Team#1]-Could not initialize proxy - no Session.

1. Is there something wrong with my mapping?
2. If not, any suggestion on how I can handle the error?

Thanks.

Comment: This does not sound like a mapping problem, but a problem of disposing or closing a session to early.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is not with your mapping, but with your session handling.

You are closing the session and then trying to access a lazily-loaded property (a Team).

Comment: This was correct. I was however using ASP.NET MVC and because of this I had to implement some extra functionality to handle lazy-loading with views.